# Как правильно: "неподаренный" или "не подаренный"?

Tags: частица-не

Мне кажется что "не подаренный".

Я перед тобой с тяжелой виною за каждый цветок неподаренный мною

Comment: Заголовок вопроса сильно путает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причастие пишется раздельно с частицей НЕ, если имеется пояснительное слово, каким в данном предложении является слово "мною"

Answer (score 0):

Точнее - зависимое слово. А причастие с зависимыми словами - это причастный оборот. Который, кстати, в данном случае обособляется, т.к. определяемое сущ. стоит перед прич. оборотом: цветок, не подаренный мною.

Comment: Уважаемая Инна! Розенталь называет слова пояснительными, а не зависимыми. Наверное, так вернее, ибо иногда такие слова связаны с определяемыми только по смыслу, без формальных элементов типа падежа.

Comment: Вопрос терминологии, а потому бессодержателен (вне специального контекста).
Оба названия одновременно и правильны, и не очень, ибо как термины они, названия, сами нуждаются в пояснении.    
Зато про обособление верно.